# C# Handle without a form

Tags: c#, message, volume, handle

Im trying to get my program to send messages to control volume but I need a handle.
I currently tried to use broadcast as seen below in the current code but that would cause all processes to send a message causing volume to go up to 100 or 0 and freezing the program. Ive tried using Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle; but that only works if I have a form or command prompt. Note I wish to have this program work using my a modification of my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace Utilities
    {
        static class VolumeMessage
        {
            private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
            private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
            private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
            private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
            private static IntPtr Handle = (IntPtr)0xffff;

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
                IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            public static void Mute()
            {
                SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle,
                    (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
            }

            public static void volumeDown()
            {
                SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle,
                    (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
            }

            public static void volumeUp()
            {
                SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle,
                    (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wish to use my pre-existing code that already works under normal circumstances and fit it to work without a form or window.

Comment: @MINIMAN10000 Why do you have to use your existing code? Sending volume up down messages is likely not the best way to do this. There would be an API for adjusting the volume

Answer (score 1):

You can use

var handle = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").First().MainWindowHandle;

Note that for the second parameter you can pass IntPtr.Zero

BTW I faced the same problem, also with mute/volume control...

Answer (score 0):

I think you sometimes just need a form to get windows messages working right, so create one and make it always hidden. We've had to so this previously for something along these lines.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do it this way then you could send it to the desktop hwnd I believe. From memory there is an API to get this hwnd which is just something like GetDesktopWindow or something like that.

However there has got to be a better way. Surely an API exists to directly control the volume.